# c# X509Certificate2: reading of abortive login count

Tags: c#, authentication, x509certificate2, rsacryptoserviceprovider

I use the .net framework to handle with certificates. Now I have a problem, with reading of abortive login count. 
I'm reading the certificate on many ways. One of them is this:

```
public X509Certificate2 ByteArrayToCertificate(byte[] buffer)
{
    var certificate = new X509Certificate2();
    try
    {
        certificate.Import(buffer);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // ... my error handling
    }

    return certificate;
}
```

I would like to know how many login attempts have failed. Because if it was to offten, the smartcard is blocked and I have no chance to use them yet.

Do yu now any way, how I can do this?

edit: An additional important Information is, how I set the Smartcard pin:

```
private RSACryptoServiceProvider CreateServiceProvider(AsymmetricAlgorithm privateKey, SecureString password)
{
    var rsa = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)privateKey;
    var parameters = new CspParameters { KeyContainerName = rsa.CspKeyContainerInfo.KeyContainerName, ProviderName = rsa.CspKeyContainerInfo.ProviderName, ProviderType = rsa.CspKeyContainerInfo.ProviderType, Flags = CspProviderFlags.NoPrompt, KeyPassword = password };

    RSACryptoServiceProvider serviceProvider = null;
    try
    {
        serviceProvider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(parameters);
    }
    catch (CryptographicException e)
    {
        // ... my error handling        
    }

    return serviceProvider;
}
```

When the pin was wrong, the counter counts the possible login attemps down. If it's 0, the smartcard is unuseable.

Comment: You would have to read the manual of this smart card so as to know whether it uses a special extension or another API for you to query. The .NET class aims to expose X509 standard info, and that counter is not part of the standard if I remember it correctly.

Comment: Thank you for the infomation. I have got a Manual of the reader, but not of the smartcard. The smartcards I have from my customer (I would ask him). Thx!